# Input fails after killing less(1) subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I'm writing a program which displays text on the terminal using Unix less(1). Here is the relevant portion:

```
less = subprocess.Popen(['less -F -'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stdout=sys.stdout, shell=True)
try:
    less.stdin.write(rfc_text)
    less.stdin.flush()
    less.stdin = sys.stdin
    less.wait()
except IOError:
    less.terminate()
    return errno.EPIPE
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    less.terminate()
    return 0
```

While waiting for less to finish, I listen for the KeyboardInterrupt exception. If I catch one, I kill less with a SIGTERM signal, and exit my program.

Now, when that happens, I'm returned to my shell prompt, but the shell no longer echoes what I write and I have to do a reset(1) to make it work again.

Any ideas on how to make less die without taking my stdin with it into the grave? The full source is available on https://github.com/jforberg/rfc/blob/master/rfc.py

**EDIT:** After some experimenting, I have found out that both less(1) and man(1) by default ignore the control-C stroke. So simply ignoring it may be a viable option. I'm not sure I think it's the proper way to do it though, so if someone has suggestions I'm still very much interested.

Comment: As a cheap workaround, you could put an `os.system('reset')` in the end of your script.  The proper solution will probably involve stopping `less` politely, i.e. writing a sigint and 'q' to it's stdin and then waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @wim re your "proper solution": Of course! The thought of writing the 'q' to less myself had not occured to me. Even after some time of programming Linux, I still have to be reminded that everything is a file. Please move that into an Answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: As there are no `setpgid` tricks, `less` should be in the same process group as your Python process, so it would receive the same ^C as your Python process.  I suppose it tries to do its own special handling, though…  How about using `-e` (`--quit-at-eof`) so that it'll exit after your program hangs up?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to ask user to exit `less` properly (by pressing `q`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen(['less'], stdin=PIPE)
try:
    p.communicate(''.join("%d\n" % i for i in range(1000)))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Press `q` to exit.")
    p.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options:

1. Less, man and related programs don't terminate upon control-C, they just abort whatever operation they are doing at the moment. So simply ignoring the keystroke seems to be an option. This would retain the useful feature that lengthy operations, such as long searches, can be aborted without terminating the program. It is also desireable for the program to function like similar programs (in this case, Unix man).
2. Less accepts the -K option which will make it terminate upon control-C, just like most non-interactive commands do.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ah! The J.F. Sebastian solution is good, but it doesnt work in all cases. In my application I want to use "less" like "tail -f" wich is done with "less +F -S logfilename". The the user has to press CTRL+C to enter in normal mode, and them Q to exit.

In order to this procedure occur without problems, I've come up with the following 6-line solution (based on J.F. Sebastian code):

```
logpath = os.path.join(cwd, "filename.log")
less = Popen(["less","+F","-S", logpath])
retcode = None
while retcode is None:
    try: retcode = less.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: pass
```

I think this solves the original. If your to input something to less, you may have to tweak the Popen method used: either `wait()` or `communicate(input)`.